# Pressing like button creates new page on facebook

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm a bit confused, because pressing the like button on my website, creates a new facebook page, where I'm listed as admin, an example:
I pressed the like button in this site:
http://www.inhaltsangabe.info/michael-kohlhaas

and it created this facebook page, where im now listed as admin:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Michael-Kohlhaas-Heinrich-von-Kleist/330701930311524

How is that possible? I dont want to create new pages with the like button...

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour, there should be a big message at the top of the page explaining to you that it's a virtual page representing a URL which you admin, and a user has liked.
Only the admin[s] can see it, other users won't see it.

You can use that page ID with the API to post updates to users that have liked your URL

Answer (score 0):

The URL to like defaults to the current page if you don't specify it. Make sure you have the URL of  your fan page defined, if you need details, post some code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont want likes for my fanpage, i want likes for the article. So it shows like this in the Newsfeed: xy has liked "name of article with link to the article" on xy